# perl: Access contents on Apache server with Directory Listing enabled

Tags: perl

I have a apache server configured for directory listing.
The url is like `http://example.com/pub-dir/`
I am able to access the contents of `pub-dir` on my web browser.

I am attempting to create a utility to list directory contents over command line using perl.

is there a simpler way to do so, other then manually parsing the html response to detect files and directories ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want a command line utility to read the directory listing from the URL and print it out?

Comment: Yes, I am teying to build the command line utility using perl from scratch. As I need to preform a set of operations bsed on the fiies and directories I am able to find on the server using the URL.

Comment: Take a look at WWW::Mechanize.  That should have the functions in it to do what you want.

Comment: You will have to parse the HTML response, but there are various ways of making parsing easy. This will only work for standard file listings for that particular web server, because the HTML for directory listings is not standardised. It sounds like FTP rather than HTTP would be the protocol of choice, but that's obviously not an option if you do not control the server machine.